# Parsing nested tags with BeautifulSoup and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to `BeautifulSoup`. I was trying to parse an HTML web page with `requests`. Code I wrote for now is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "SOME_URL"
f = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.text, 'html.parser')
for el in (soup.findAll("td",{"class": "g-res-tab-cell"})):
    print(el)
    exit
```

The output is as follows:

```
<td class="g-res-tab-cell">
    <div style="padding:8px;">
        <div style="padding-top:8px;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <div itemscope itemtype="URL">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="g-res-tab-cell" style="width:100%;">
                                        <div style="width:100%;padding-left:4px;">
                                            <div class="subtext_view_med" itemprop="name">
                                                <a href="NAME1-URL" itemprop="url">NAME1</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="direction:ltr;padding-left:5px;margin-bottom:2px;" class="smtext">
                                                <span class="Gray">In English:</span> ENGLISH_NAME1
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="padding-bottom:2px;padding-top:8px;font-size:14px;text-align:justify;min-height:158px;" itemprop="description">DESCRIPTION1</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <div itemscope itemtype="URL">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="g-res-tab-cell" style="width:100%;">
                                        <div style="width:100%;padding-left:4px;">
                                            <div class="subtext_view_med" itemprop="name">
                                                <a href="NAME2-URL" itemprop="url">NAME2</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="direction:ltr;padding-left:5px;margin-bottom:2px;" class="smtext">
                                                <span class="Gray">In English:</span> ENGLISH_NAME2
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="padding-bottom:2px;padding-top:8px;font-size:14px;text-align:justify;min-height:158px;" itemprop="description">DESCRIPTION2</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Now I got stuck. I'm trying to parse the `NAME`, `DESCRIPTION` and `ENGLISH_NAME` for each block. I would like to print each one of them so the output will be:

```
name = NAME1
en_name = ENGLISH_NAME1
description = DESCRIPTION1
name = NAME2
en_name = ENGLISH_NAME2
description = DESCRIPTION2
```

I tried to read the docs but I could not find how to treat nested attributes especially without a `class` or `id` name. As I understand, each block starts with `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">`. In each block I should find tag `a` that has `itemprop="url"` and get the `NAME`. Then in `<span class="Gray">In English:</span>` get the `en_name` and in `itemprop="description"` get the `description`. But I feels like `BeautifulSoup` can't do it (or at least very hard to achieve it). How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each `td` with class `g-res-tab-cell` using `soup.find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(content, 'html.parser').td.find_all('td', {'class':'g-res-tab-cell'})
results = [[i.find('div', {'class':'subtext_view_med'}).a.text, i.find('div', {'class':'smtext'}).contents[1].text, i.find('div', {'itemprop':'description'}).text] for i in d]
```

Output:

```
[['NAME1', 'In English:', 'DESCRIPTION1'], ['NAME2', 'In English:', 'DESCRIPTION2']]
```

Edit: from link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.sratim.co.il/browsenewmovies.php?page=1').text, 'html.parser')
movies = d.find_all('div', {'itemtype':'http://schema.org/Movie'})
result = [[getattr(i.find('a', {'itemprop':'url'}), 'text', 'N/A'), getattr(i.find('div', {'class':'smtext'}), 'text', 'N/A'), getattr(i.find('div', {'itemprop':'description'}), 'text', 'N/A')] for i in movies]
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I get an error. My guess is because I don't understand what `content`  should be. should it be `content = requests.get(link)` or `content = soup(f.text, 'html.parser').findAll("td",{"class": "g-res-tab-cell"})`? (both of them fail). The html I showed is not the full HTML I'm parsing

Comment: @vesii Yes, `content` is the result of `requests.get(link).text`. If possible, can you post the link to the site you are scraping? Thank you.

Comment: I switched to the SO chat (hope you are available to answer there)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. As that information is present for all films you should have a fully populated result set.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://www.sratim.co.il/browsenewmovies.php?page=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
names = [item.text for item in soup.select('[itemprop=url]')]  #32
english_names = [item.next_sibling for item in soup.select('.smtext:contains("In English: ") span')]
descriptions = [item.text for item in soup.select('[itemprop=description]')]
results = list(zip(names, english_names, descriptions))
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Name', 'English_Name', 'Description'])
print(df)
```